# Cannot parse json data from ajax call. Attempted fixes cause me to go in circles. Why?

Tags: javascript, json, debugging, parsing, jquery

**UPDATE**: @MESSIAH told me to shorten this. Here is the bare bones version.

I cannot parse my response from an ajax call. I keep going in circles. Google is basically telling me that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654004/parsing-json-ajax-response) is the problem. Well, no matter if I take out json in the ajax call or call parse. It will give me errors.

If parse directly without using JSON.parse(), I get: 
The first one is: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'time' of undefined` 
***Okay, so that means it is not parsed.***

Currently, I am getting this because I am trying to parse: 
The one I am getting right now is: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u` 
***Okay, so that means it is parsed***.

Here is my ajax call:

```
var reply;
    function sendRouteRequest()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: '/api/getReply',
            data: data, 
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result)
            {
                reply = result;
                console.log(reply);
                console.log(reply.time);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert("Error: " + textStatus + " exception: " + errorThrown);
            }

        });//End of ajax


    }
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
function parseJson()
{
    //data = JSON.stringify(reply);
    jsonData = JSON.parse(reply);   
    console.log(jsonData.time);    
}
```

Here is what the reply looks like in console.

```
Object
alert: Object
points: Array[30]
points: Array[30]
time: 4.72
__proto__: Object
status: Object
__proto__: Object
```

But console.log(reply.time) gives me undefined. Wut?

Going in circles.

Geeky

**UPDATE**: I am calling parseJson() in a function not shown here, `$(document).ready(function(){ //blah blah blah}`

Servlet returns application/json format

Comment: From your log, it looks already parsed (i.e., an object, not a string). On the other hand I don't see you calling parseJson anywhere...

Comment: if the content-type from the server is json, doesn't jQuery turn it into an object for you?

Comment: @bfavaretto I updated my answer to explain that. My problem is if it is already parsed, then why the first error, right?

Comment: @Geeky:believe me you wont get any replies unless you make your question 3 times shorter.just post the relevant part!!!

Comment: Maybe you're trying to read the response before it arrives, or it's out of scope. We'd have to see more from your code to tell.

Comment: @bfvaretto I think a key to understanding this thing is why console.log(reply.time) gives me undefined.

Comment: first apparently reply is not a valid JSON string to be parsed. when you specify data type to be 'json' it was already pasred to JSON. change datatype to  'text' and print result again.

Comment: @bfvaretto I got it working. The key was the structure of the json. Since the servlet sent it as a application/json, the information I wanted had a new layer on it. So I accessed it using this format reply.alert.time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't look good response. for eg why there are two points.

```
points: Array[30]
points: Array[30]
```

Can you print out the response what you get. It looks like javascript object and not JSON response.

if it is json response then it should look something like

```
[{"alerts" : {}, "points": [], "time": 4.72 ......}]
```

I think you uncomment this line

```
dataType: 'json',
```

Comment: Yes, also to access what I need, I need to call the json object like console.log(reply.alert.time). Then it works!

Comment: I will go ahead and count this as the answer with both of our comments combined. This was really the start of the answer, but the key was accessing the structure as reply.alert.time.